# Codeigniter - NGINX How to Remove index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

**Issue Details**

Description : adding nginx custom.conf is not working for me. It is showing below error

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.18.0
```

but if I add index.php/ before classname in URL then it works fine

Please let me know how to remove index.php from url with Elastickbeanstalk + nginx + codeigniter setup

Below mention are the full details of my application

**Version**

```
PHP 7.4
Codeignter 3.10
```

**Deployment Setup**

```
AWS
ElasticBeanstalk
NGINX
```

**MY Application Setup**

```
.platform
  -nginx
     -conf.d
        -custom.conf
-Application
-Controller
-Views
-Model
...
...
..
```

**Custom Config**
custom.conf

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      server {
        server_name http://domain.tld/;

        root /var/www;
        index index.html index.php;

        # set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
        location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location / {
                # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                include fastcgi.conf;
        }
    }
```

**My config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://domain.tld/";
$config['index_page']       = "";
$config['uri_protocol']     = "REQUEST_URI";
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Have you reviewed your log files?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes nginx logs "2020/12/07 12:41:28.905128 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetTailLogs
2020/12/07 12:41:28.905135 [INFO] Tail Logs...
2020/12/07 12:41:28.906315 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-engine.log"

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by entering correct path for proxy conf.

Thank you Xaver!